# Is there a way to tap into the CoreAnimation completion curve mathematics for custom animations?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

For various reasons, I am animating manually using a `CADisplayLink`:

```
- (void)update:(CADisplayLink *)sender;
{
    // Linearly interpolate proportion animated based on elapsed time
    CGFloat proportion = ... 

    [self updateAnimationForProportion:proportion];
}
```

I want a `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` instead of a linear calculation.

- Is it possible to get a callback from CoreAnimation instead of implementing the mathematics manually?
- Or even better, is it possible to using the iOS7 physics based animation?

  ```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0
       usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
        initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                      options:0 animations:^{ ... } completion:nil];
  ```

Comment: Seems like there is not an answer so someone wrote it manually.  https://gist.github.com/raphaelschaad/6739676

Answer (score 1):

Nope not possible it seems.

If it helps anyone looking to use ease curves in iOS, I took this list of handy ease curves from jquery.easing.1.3 and ported them to be useable in C as a simple header file (,C++,Objective-C,etc):

https://gist.github.com/MeteC/10012959

Comment: That's really nice.  I was wondering if it was possible to get a nice bounce using a CAMediaTimingFunction curve if the control points were allowed to go above 1.0.  http://netcetera.org/camtf-playground.html  Ill give your port a go.